# Sharepoint Automation with C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a document repository on Sharepoint where new Excel spreadsheets are deposited daily. I need to create a Windows service that reads this folder where the documents are deposited daily and loads the data from these spreadsheets into my database. My question is:

1. How to create a connection to Sharepoint via C# code;
2. How to read the folders and check if there are new documents in the mentioned Sharepoint folder.

Furthermore, any prototype code to take a first step towards my programming or indication of any Git repository that shows information focused on this subject will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much for your attention and suggestions.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the Graph API for this.  [This is a good place to get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).  Even though document libraries in SharePoint are just lists with attachments, they are not exposed via Lists in Graph.  You will need to access them through Drive objects (as in OneDrive) instead.  If you keep in mind that OneDrive is actually hosted on SharePoint, this will make much more sense.
Begin by getting the Drive object for your target site like this:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var drive = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Drive.Request().GetAsync();
```

Once you have the Drive object, you will need to begin an iterative process of getting the items in the root followed by getting any children of root items i.e. folders etc. like this:

```
foreach (var rootItem in await drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync())
{
    foreach (var child in await rootItem.Children.Request().GetAsync())
    {
        //Do something with the child item
    }
}
```